# How can I have a centered single border between columns?

Tags: html, css, sass, grid, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get the effect of where you have a single line between columns using a grid ([foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/)). Please see this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grZZLG/) for extra clarity.

I'm trying to create this 
[image: grid]

But the spacing between the columns doesn't allow me to do this by simply using a `border-right` for example. I'd rather not remove the spacing for responsive reasons.

I end up with this just using a border.
[image]

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want a border on the left, right and bottom? Or do you want those removed? I can't tell if your image is cut off, or if you want it that way.

Comment: Yes, I wish to have it exactly the same as the image but won't the removal of the padding on the `.column` affect responsiveness as it is there by default? `.text-center` just applies a `text-align:center`.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Answer has been updated. Let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by first removing the padding that is in your `.columns` divs. This will allow all the divs to be right next to each other. Then, apply the border to the top, and right sides of your `.columns`. Finally, add a `:last-child` selector and remove the right border to it.

**Result**

[image]

**SCSS**

```
.columns {
  padding: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  .wrap {
    padding: 5px;
    p {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
  &:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxj2xua6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it by creating borders with pseudo-elements.

```
.wrap {position:relative;}
.row > .columns:not(:last-child) > .wrap:after {
    content:""; 
    position:absolute; 
    right:-16px; /* ~30px gutters */
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    width:1px; 
    background:blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAzKEy

That'll work if your items are all equal height.  If not, you might need to use pseudo-elements on an ancestor element, but the idea is similar.